# How to import certs into non-root Java container

Tags: java, certificate, keytool

I'm developing a Java container that connects an external server using HTTPS as a part of my product.

As the external server's certificate differs from customer to customer, it's not possible to import the cert beforehand.

So I wrote a shell so that the container can import all certs located in a specific directory that mounts a directory of a host machine.

Dockerfile:

```
...
ENTRYPOINT ["entrypoint.sh"]
```

entrypoint.sh:

```sh
#!/bin/sh

# Import certs
for cert in `ls /mydirectory/certs`
do
  alias=`echo $cert | sed 's/\.[^\.]*$//'`
  /opt/jdk-15/bin/keytool -importcert -alias $alias -cacerts -storepass changeit -file /mydirectory/$cert -noprompt
done

# Start the main process
java -jar /mydirectory/test.jar
```

However, since the container runs as a non-root user, I got the following error when the container started:

```
Certificate was added to keystore
keytool error: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /opt/jdk-15/lib/security/cacerts (Permission denied)
```

The default permission of `cacerts` was 644 so I could manage the problem by describing `RUN chmod 666 /opt/jdk-15/lib/security/cacerts` in the Dockerfile but  I'm not sure this is a good way.
Is there any proper way to import certs when the container runs as a non-root?

Comment: Great question. I would also love the answer.

Answer (score 1):

The only way I found is to create a new truststore and import everything from the default one.
I've added this to the beginning of the  `entrypoint` of container

```
keytool -import -trustcacerts -alias newCa -keystore /somePath/newKeyStore -file /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/newCa.crt -noprompt -storepass changeit && 
keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk/jre/lib/security/cacerts -destkeystore /somePath/newKeyStore -srcstorepass changeit -deststorepass changeit
```

on top of it you need to pass this new keystore to java options either in the command that run java or with env vars like `_JAVA_OPTS`

```
-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=/somePath/newKeyStore
-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=changeit
```